# Get different Column value when current row checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been looking around everywhere for a solution and I just can't find any.
What I'm trying to do here is get the third column value i.e price when the checkbox in the first column is selected. I'll eventually use the column value to calculate the total which will be thrown into a div.

```
<body>
    <form action="" method="post"><table id="tableid">
        <tr>
            <th><b>Menu:</b></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" name="item" value="27"></td>
            <td>Item1</td>
            <td class="">100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" name="item" value="28"></td>
            <td>Item2</td><td class="">200</td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" name="item" value="29"></td>
            <td>Item3</td>
            <td class="">300</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" name="item" value="30"></td>
            <td>Item4</td>
            <td class="">400</td>   
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

I've tried several options from $(this).parent().find()....and nth-child() but i don't seem to be getting how "this" works

sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chkbx').change(function(){
    $('.chkbx:checked').each(function(){
        total+=parseInt($(this).parent().find("td").text());
    });
    //var item=$(".chkbx tr:nth-child(2)").text();
    $("#container").html(total);
    });
});
```

Is my approach wrong? How should I go about this? Will using classes be of any help?

Thanks in Advance!!
P.S: Very new to JS and JQuery.

Comment: `parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(2)").text(), 10)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target last `td` element so you can use `.closest()` to traverse up-to `<TR>` then use `.eq(index)`<sup>1</sup> to target the desired element

```
total+= parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(2)").text(), 10);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.chkbx').change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.chkbx:checked').each(function() {
      total += parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find("td:eq(2)").text(), 10);
    });
    console.clear();
    console.log(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableid">
  <tr>
    <th><b>Menu:</b></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" name="item" value="27"></td>
    <td>Item1</td>
    <td class="">100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" name="item" value="28"></td>
    <td>Item2</td>
    <td class="">200</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" name="item" value="29"></td>
    <td>Item3</td>
    <td class="">300</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" name="item" value="30"></td>
    <td>Item4</td>
    <td class="">400</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>I would recommend, assigning a CSS class to target the element rather than using index.</sub>

*HTML*

```
<td class="price">400</td>
```

*Script*

```
total+= parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find("td.price").text(), 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `siblings` with `last` like this.

```
  $(this).parent().siblings(":last").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use need to use `closest()` to find the tr then use find with `:nth-child()` to get the specific td

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chkbx').change(function(){
    var total = 0;
    $('.chkbx:checked').each(function(){
        total+=parseInt($(this).closest('tr').find("td:nth-child(3)").text());
    });
    //var item=$(".chkbx tr:nth-child(2)").text();
    $("#container").text(total);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post"><table id="tableid">
    <tr>
        <th><b>Menu:</b></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" name="item" value="27"></td>
        <td>Item1</td>
        <td class="">100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" name="item" value="28"></td>
        <td>Item2</td><td class="">200</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" name="item" value="29"></td>
        <td>Item3</td>
        <td class="">300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" name="item" value="30"></td>
        <td>Item4</td>
        <td class="">400</td>   
    </tr>
</table>
</form>

<span id='container'> </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You were not tracking the `TD` for `price` column correctly, and you need to declare the total variable outside the `.each()` otherwise the scope wont allow to access the variable and populate the total, see below for a demo

```js
var total = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.chkbx').change(function() {

    $('.chkbx:checked').each(function() {
      //console.log($(this).parent().next().next().text());
      total += parseInt($(this).parent().next().next().text());
    });

    //var item=$(".chkbx tr:nth-child(2)").text();
    $("#container").html(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
TOTAL
<div id="container"></div>
<form action="" method="post">
  <table id="tableid">
    <tr>
      <th><b>Menu:</b></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" name="item" value="27"></td>
      <td>Item1</td>
      <td class="">100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" name="item" value="28"></td>
      <td>Item2</td>
      <td class="">200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" name="item" value="29"></td>
      <td>Item3</td>
      <td class="">300</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="chkbx" name="item" value="30"></td>
      <td>Item4</td>
      <td class="">400</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```